# Exception: "Can't perform Create, Update, or Delete operations on 'Table(Property_main_image)' because it has no primary key."

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am inserting an image in the folder and its url in database but it throws some kind of exception. I am using linq to sql.

it inserted the picture successfully in the folder but does not inserts the path in the database and throws the exception.

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       using (Property_dbDataContext context = new Property_dbDataContext())
         {
            string imagename = _PictureUpload1.FileName.ToString();
            Property_main_image main = new Property_main_image();
            main.prop_id = "5";
            string imagepath_2 = "wp-content/uploads/Main_Images/" + imagename;
            main.image_url = imagepath_2.ToString();
            _PictureUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imagepath_2));
            context.Property_main_images.InsertOnSubmit(main);
            context.SubmitChanges();
         }
    }
```

Exception:

> ***Can't perform Create, Update, or Delete operations on 'Table(Property_main_image)' because it has no primary key.***
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: Can't perform Create, Update, or Delete operations on 'Table(Property_main_image)'
>   because it has no primary key.

Comment: Can you post the `Property_main_image` model?

Comment: the exception says all your model does not have primary key

Comment: possible duplicate of [linq Can't perform Create, Update, or Delete operations on 'Table(req)' because it has no primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748847/linq-cant-perform-create-update-or-delete-operations-on-tablereq-because)

Comment: i have used the primary key in it.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ does not allow to insert data into table without primary key. To achieve the insert data with table without primary key you can either use store procedure or create a query and execute using LINQ.

Comment: this is'nt the first query i am using with linq, i have been using linq for long but this is the first time i am getting this kind of exception and i have a primary in the table..

Answer (score 1):

LINQ does not allow to insert data into table without primary key.
so firstly Create primary key after that refresh .dbml file that means delete data class(means table) and again add.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the error is misleading?  I'm pretty new to C# so for what it's worth.  I had the same problem and error.  Even though I defined the PrimaryKey when I built the table as public I got the no primary key error at a point in the program.  Since it didn't make sense I built the primary key again before making the call and ran the program and got the following error.

{"These columns don't currently have unique values."}

At least in my case this was true.  I had multiple rows with same primary key value.  I added another column to the primary key to ensure it was unique.